# Application failure when deploying heroku app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, deployment

I run `heroku open` I get an application error. I check the logs and this is there:

> 2016-06-19T05:22:44.640391+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10
>   desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=drawparty-.herokuapp.com
>   request_id=6712804b-95f9-49ce-92a5-7f45df7bb79e fwd="108.172.11.245"
>   dyno= connect= service= status=503

I cannot seem to fix this error. Some things I have tried:

```
heroku restart
bundle install
heroku run rake db:migrate
```

The error is H10 which is found here (where's the solution?):
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/error-codes#h10-app-crashed

Comment: The error appears to be here: `2010-10-06T21:51:09-07:00 app[web.1]: Missing the Rails 2.3.5 gem. Please `gem install -v=2.3.5 rails`, update your RAILS_GEM_VERSION setting in config/environment.rb for the Rails version you do have installed, or comment out RAILS_GEM_VERSION to use the latest version installed.
`. Are you intentionally using Rails 2? That's an old version.

Comment: I'm using 4.2.6 rails.  That's my mistake. I linked to the H10 error because it said "code=H10" in my logs....however the logs don't mention any version problems so I don't think that's it.

Comment: can you share the entry point to your app. Also include the Rails12factor gem and check your logs properly the main cause of this sort of crash is always included

Answer (score 2):

This is in all likelihood caused by your gems and which environments you've specified them in. Heroku requires some default gems in your production ENV such as [rails_12factor](https://github.com/heroku/rails_12factor) & [pg](https://deveiate.org/code/pg/).

```
group :production do 
  gem 'rails_12factor'
  gem 'pg'
end
```

PG acts as the interface between Rails and PostgreSQL DB's, which is the default DB for Heroku, BUT not in in a new Rails App.